# Universal PLIST reader with codable structure

Tags: swift, plist, codable

My plist-reader works well with a specific structure, but crashes when I try to make it universal.
Here is a specific structure edition (works well):

```
struct Auth0_: Codable {
    let domain: String
    let clientId: String
}

extension Bundle {
    
    func decodePlist(plistName: String) -> Auth0_ {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: plistName, withExtension: "plist") else {
            fatalError("There is no such plist-file \(plistName).")
        }
        
        guard
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: path),
            let dict = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Auth0_.self, from: data)
        else {
            fatalError("Cannot convert plist \(plistName) to JSON.")
        }
                
        return dict
    }
}

let dict = Bundle.main.decodePlist(plistName: "Auth0")
```

Then I try to make function `<T: Codable>` and get the fatal error

> Cannot convert plist...

```
struct Auth0_: Codable {
    let Domain: String
    let ClientId: String
}

extension Bundle {

    func decodePlist<T: Codable>(plistName: String) -> T {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: plistName, withExtension: "plist") else {
            fatalError("There is no such plist-file \(plistName).")
        }
        
        guard
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: path),
            let dict = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        else {
            fatalError("Cannot convert plist \(plistName) to JSON.")
        }
                
        return dict
    }
}

let dict: [Auth0_] = Bundle.main.decodePlist(plistName: "Auth0")
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Isolate the lines. You have two lines that make the `fatalError`. So find which one doesn't work. Also, since you can't find the error yourself (not enougth debugging skill yet), NEVER use `try?`, use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch`, and you'll see your error. If you didn't changed your plist, then `[Auth0_]` this parts says use `[Auth0_].self` in the `PropertyListDecoder` line, which is wrong, since you have `Auth0_`, not a `[Auth0_]` (ie `Array<Auth0_>`). Also, `let dict: [Auth0_]` is miselading, since it's an array declaration, not a dictionary.

Comment: Larme has provided an excellent answer but I wanted to also add that your error message is very confusing. You are decoding the plist to a struct, not converting it to JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you haven't changed your plist content in the two codes.

You have two lines of cause that can cause the `fatalError`.

```
guard
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: path),
    let dict = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
else {
    fatalError("Cannot convert plist \(plistName) to JSON.")
}
```

Debugging start to find the reason, so let's split them:

```
guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: path) else {
    fatalError("Cannot convert read plist data \(plistName).")
}
guard let dict = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else {
    fatalError("Cannot convert plist \(plistName) to JSON.")
}
```

Now, we can see that's the second line that is causing the issue.

Now, I'd strongly suggest to `NEVER` use `try?` (with a question mark) when you don't know how to debug it. Use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch`:

```
do {
    let dict = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
} catch {
        fatalError("Cannot convert plist \(plistName) to JSON error: \(error)")
}
```

Now, you should get an error about decoding issue, with explicit info:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, 
             Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], 
                                         debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", 
                                         underlyingError: nil))
```

So it says that at the top level (`codingPath` being empty), it expects an array, but found a dictionary instead.

Why is that happening?

Because when you wrote `let dict: [Auth0_] = Bundle.main.decodePlist(plistName: "Auth0")`, it then did `let dict = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([Auth0_].self, from: data)`, which is different from what you used before when the code was specific and not generic.

So it should be:

```
let dict: Auth0_ = Bundle.main.decodePlist(plistName: "Auth0")
```

Now, if we look at your code with error, you wrote `let dict: [Auth0_] = ...`, but `[Auth0_]`, that's `Array<Auth0_>`, so you expected it to have an array (ie a list), of `Auth0_`, but you have one only, and that's not a list of one element. So the naming was misleading at start.

Side note:
You are just decoding, so you shouldn't need to restrict it to `Codable`, but only `Decodable`. Since `Codable` is `Encodable` + `Decodable`.